# Add keys to collection of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in JavaScript like this:

```
[
  {A:10},
  {B:20},
  {C:30}
]
```

I'm trying to convert this into an array of objects that would appear like this (to work with d3.js):

```
[
  {word: "A", weight: 10},
  {word: "B", weight: 20},
  {word: "C", weight: 30}
]
```

I'm able to get the initial array of objects by simply doing:

```
var wordData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (wordData.hasOwnProperty(words[i])) {
        wordData[words[i]] += 1;
    } else {
        wordData[words[i]] = 1;
    }
}
```

This just sets up a simple hash, but doesn't add the keys before each one.

**Edit**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariocatch/peayr88z/) for simplicity.

Comment: You need to iterate twice.

Comment: But `{A, 10}` doesn't look like a valid javascript, it should be `{A:10}`.

Comment: Correction made, thankyou @nicael

Comment: *occurrence count* - your expected output doesn't reflect that

Comment: Sure it does :) Just know that the `weight` value is the number of times that key (`word`) has occurred through iterating an array of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var wordData = [
  {A: 10},
  {B: 20},
  {C: 30}
];

var result = wordData.map(function (item) {
    var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    return {word: key, weight: item[key]};
});
```

Comment: This is probably the answer, but I can't get it to work. I don't understand why my source collection `wordData` has a length of one when I test it locally. I'm updating my question with a new edit that shows what the Chrome inspector is showing it as. It's probably because of the way I'm creating the `wordData` object. Edit 3 is the newest edit.

Comment: @mariocatch Instead of a screenshot you might want to post the output of `JSON.stringify(wordData, null, 2)`...

Comment: Well then your initial assumption ("I have an array of objects") is wrong. ;) Show the code that constructs your "array".

Comment: I've edited the long question, and added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariocatch/peayr88z/) which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Well, change `var wordData = [];` to `var wordData = {};`, obviously. ;)

Comment: Lol, that definitely simplifies things. It doesn't exactly give the output I'm looking for with [this edited jsfiddle to show the expected output](https://jsfiddle.net/mariocatch/peayr88z/4/). Trying to construct that output

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. I have tried with for loop.

```
var wordData =[
{A: 10},
{B: 20},
{C: 30}
];

var results = [];
for (var prop in wordData) {                    
    var key = Object.keys(wordData[prop])[0];
    result = {word: key, weight: wordData[prop][key]};
    results.push(result);
}

var json_result = JSON.stringify(results, null, 2);
console.log(json_result);
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "word": "A",
    "weight": 10
  },
  {
    "word": "B",
    "weight": 20
  },
  {
    "word": "C",
    "weight": 30
  }
]
```

or

```
var json_result = JSON.stringify(results); // without null
console.log(json_result);
```

output

```
[{"word":"A","weight":10},{"word":"B","weight":20},{"word":"C","weight":30}]

<div id="data">
  Run the code below
</div>

var wordData = {}; // Edit, use {} intead of [] here.
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // The problem is definitely in this loop.
  if (wordData.hasOwnProperty(words[i])) {
    wordData[words[i]] += 1;
  } else {
    wordData[words[i]] = 1;
  }
}

var results = [];
for (var prop in wordData) {  
    result = {word: prop, weight: wordData[prop]};
    results.push(result);
}
var json_result = JSON.stringify(results, null, 2);
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = json_result;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/peayr88z/8/)

Comment: I've reproduced your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mariocatch/peayr88z/5/

It's providing empty objects in the array at the moment in that example.